# android no such column: _id

Tags: android, database

I'm trying to feed a listview with a custom cursorAdapter.

I get this error : `03-16 03:25:39.968: E/AndroidRuntime(14552): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: _id: , while compiling: SELECT _id, content_note FROM notes`

at this line `values.put(DataBaseHelper.DATABASEBASE_CONTENT_NOTE, note.getContent());`

Here are my 2 Connections classes

```
    package com.android.database;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db";
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE_NOTE = "notes";
    public static final String DATABASE_ID_NOTE = "_id";
    public static final String DATABASE_CONTENT_NOTE = "content_note";

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE_NOTE + " (" + DATABASE_ID_NOTE + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + DATABASE_CONTENT_NOTE + " TEXT);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        android.util.Log.w("Constants", "Maj de la base, suppression de toutes les anciennes donnees");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Notes");
        onCreate(db);
    }

}



    package com.android.database;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class NoteDataSource{

    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;
    private String[] allColumns = { DataBaseHelper.DATABASE_ID_NOTE,
            DataBaseHelper.DATABASE_CONTENT_NOTE };

    public NoteDataSource(Context context) {
        dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context);
    }


    public void open() throws SQLException {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    public Cursor createNoteTop(String note) {

        //recuperer le bon id

//      int idNote = getFirstId().getId();
        int idNote = 1 ;

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DataBaseHelper.DATABASE_ID_NOTE, idNote);
        values.put(DataBaseHelper.DATABASE_CONTENT_NOTE, note);
        long insertId = database.insert(DataBaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE_NOTE, null,
                values);
        Cursor cursor = database.query(DataBaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE_NOTE,
                allColumns, DataBaseHelper.DATABASE_ID_NOTE + " = " + insertId, null,
                null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor;
    }

    public Cursor createNoteBottom(String note) {

        //recuperer le bon id

        int idNote = getLastId().getId();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DataBaseHelper.DATABASE_ID_NOTE, idNote);
        values.put(DataBaseHelper.DATABASE_CONTENT_NOTE, note);
        long insertId = database.insert(DataBaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE_NOTE, null,
                values);
        // To show how to query
        Cursor cursor = database.query(DataBaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE_NOTE,
                allColumns, DataBaseHelper.DATABASE_ID_NOTE + " = " + insertId, null,
                null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor;
    }

    public void deleteNote(Note note) {
        long id = note.getId();
        System.out.println("Note deleted with id: " + id);
        database.delete(DataBaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE_NOTE, DataBaseHelper.DATABASE_ID_NOTE
                + " = " + id, null);
    }

    public Cursor getAllNotes() {
        Cursor cursor = database.query(DataBaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE_NOTE,
                allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
        return cursor;
    }

    private Note getFirstId(){
        Note notes = new Note();
        Cursor cursor = database.query(DataBaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE_NOTE,
                allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        notes = cursorToNote(cursor);

        return notes;

    }

    private Note getLastId(){

        Note notes = new Note();
        Cursor cursor = database.query(DataBaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE_NOTE,
                allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToLast();
        notes = cursorToNote(cursor);

        return notes;

    }

    private Note cursorToNote(Cursor cursor) {
        Note note = new Note();
        note.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
        note.setContent(cursor.getString(1));
        return note;
    }




}
```

This must be simple and come from the fact that I already created base with other name fields and it doesn't upgrade.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This must be simple and come from the fact that I already created base with other name fields and it doesn't upgrade.

I guess you are right. You should increase the version number whenever you change the database. Then you can put code in `onUpgrade` that can handle the transition.

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

The schema for `onUpgrade` is usually like this

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // it all started this way
    if (oldVersion < 1) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE supertable...");
    }

    // in version 2 I decided that I need another table
    if (oldVersion < 2) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE cooltable...");
    }

    // in version 3 I decided that the table is not required anymore
    if (oldVersion < 3) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE cooltable...");
    }
    // remember to increase DATABASE_VERSION if you add steps here.
}
```

That upgrade schema will also allow users that have your app installed to upgrade the app to new versions without getting corrupted databases.

Comment: Thanks this is the thing I didn't get.

Answer (score 1):

You should ensure that your `_id` field also has the `AUTOINCREMENT` property.

I think you can also leave it out altogether and it will be automatically added correctly for you.

There's a generic overview [here](http://androidpartaker.wordpress.com/2011/07/03/introduction-to-android-sqlite-database/).

Comment: True & important point. Never do `values.put(DataBaseHelper.DATABASE_ID_NOTE, idNote);` in inserts / updates since that defeats the purpose of an auto-incrementing key.